# Cannot pass the PHP variable to the hidden input for Epayment website

Tags: php, html, hidden-field, payment-processing, website-payment-pro

This is a E-payment submit form (HTML+PHP). It shows a field that gets the `$Amount` .
This form (`$amount`) will post to a E-payment website .I tried to pass the `$Amount` to 
`<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $Amount; ?>" >` .(It works when `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3000.0" >` .)

> > Error:
>
> HTTP Status 404 - /b2cDemo/eng/payment/null
>
> > type Status report
> >
> > message /b2cDemo/eng/payment/null
> >
> > description The requested resource is not available.

Any problems here?

Secondly , is it okay to show these merchant info in my source code(HTML)? Any security issues?

```
<input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="13213123">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $Amount; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="12313221">
<input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="3213123" >

......
```

---

```
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$Amount = "";
$Amount_err ="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {...
     // Validate Amount
        $input_Amount = trim($_POST["Amount"]);
        if (empty($input_Amount)) {
            $Amount_err = "Please enter the amount.";
        } elseif (!ctype_digit($input_Amount)) {
            $Amount_err = 'Please enter a positive integer value.';
        } else {
            $Amount = $input_Amount;
        }

    .....
         <form name="Epayment" method="post" action=" a EPayment sites">

    <input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="....">//fixed code
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $Amount; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="..." >

    ......

         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($Amount_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">                             
    <label>Amount</label>                    
    <input list="Amount" name="Amount"  multiple class="form-control"> 
       <datalist id="Amount" >
        <option value="100">
        <option value="300">
        <option value="500">
        <option value="1000">
      </datalist>  
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $Amount_err; ?></span>
     </div>
```

Comment: you don't need to show anything but the amount, once you make the request, then just add the merchant id and everything else on the request

Comment: You mean I don't need to write those hidden input ,except the $amount ? But now I can't pass the $amount to the site

Comment: inside your form just take the user input, to request a POST into the epayment gateway, just simply curl it, by showing it inside the form (via hidden input tags) of course the merchant it and stuff can be seen by simply inspecting the element

Comment: Yes, I m doing this . But after I submit the form , it shows `Error:

HTTP Status 404 - /b2cDemo/eng/payment/null

type Status report

message /b2cDemo/eng/payment/null

description The requested resource is not available.` I guess the $amount cannot pass to the epayment gateway.

Comment: your form is just confusing, no need to add a hidden input for the `amount`, the input list amount is just enough, here's the steps, user inputs amount, submits the form, get the amount input, prepare merchant ids orderref and everything else, create a curl request (i prefer this) to the payment gateway including the sensitive stuff plus the amount. profit

Comment: `$Payment` should be set unless the validation fails. Do you skip creating the form when `$Amount_err` is set?

Comment: `// Check input errors before inserting in database
    if (... && empty($Amount_err) &&....) {
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $pdo = Database::connect();` If `Amount_err` occurs , it stops creating the form to db . The form does two actions: passing to Epayment gateway & own db

Comment: @Ghost According to the user Manual of the EPayment , we should use the method of hidden input . But in this case , what should I do to tackle the passing problem

Answer (score 1):

Capitalization matters. You have

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $Amount; ?>" >
```

Yet try to access it via:

```
$input_Amount = trim($_POST["Amount"]);
```

You need to change your html `name` attribute to `"Amount"` **or** your `$_POST` to `$_POST["amount"]`

Comment: He's accessing `<input list="Amount" name="Amount"  multiple class="form-control">` It has capital `A`.

Comment: The hidden input is for sending to Epayment, not his own script.

Comment: `Kindly note we do not accept symbols in the 'amount' field.` Msg shown on the epayment gateway with your method